# Do Enterprise-era humans hunt for food or not?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In "Rogue Planet", Archer states that hunting went out of style on Earth over a hundred years ago.

However, the crew of the Enterprise clearly eat meat and, in "Dead Stop", Commander Tucker would eat replicated catfish and compare it (fairly favourably) to "the real thing". So it seems clear enough that humans of this era do not replicate all of their meat with the protein resequencer.

How, then, should we reconcile these two facts? Does Archer make some distinction between "hunting" and "farming" (which seems particularly dubious in the case of fish), or is this a plot-hole? Or is there perhaps something more... sinister... going on?

Comment: I would guess he meant hunting for sport went out of style.

Comment: Don't see why farming seems dubious in the case of fish, especially catfish.  And most meat consumers eat today is 'farmed' (cattle farms, pig farms, etc).  How much hunting today is done for actual need as opposed to just sport ?

Comment: Archer hunts the most dangerous animal of all, Xindi.

Comment: @Stan I mean that there is little distinction between hunting and farming for fish, because fish are generally farmed from their natural habitat. Though fish farms do exist. And I'd forgotten about hunting for sport.

Comment: Related, but probably not duplicate as ENT is set ~230 years earlier:  [Has the human race gone vegetarian in Star Trek?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28049/has-the-human-race-gone-vegetarian-in-star-trek)

Comment: Catfish, salmon, and most shrimp are almost entirely farmed. Somewhere, someone is growing those in a man-made pond, or in the case of some shrimp and of salmon, in giant cages submerged in the shallow ocean. It's not hunting at all.

Comment: @JohnO Oh. Okay then. What about all those nets that keep tangling up dolphins and sharks?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Those are for other species of fish. If you like tuna, tuna isn't (currently) farmable. Cod isn't, haddock isn't, etc. Those are the ones that they use nets and longlines and whatnot on. Some research has been done on farming those (and since the Japanese will buy a single tuna for well over $1 million there's much demand), but it's still tricky and expensive.

Comment: @JohnO That $1m tuna is a poor example; the bid was remarkably high but the auction in question is well-known for attractive ludicrous bids for celebration and publicity. That is, this is not a good example of tuna's market price.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's not that poor of an example. We're talking about an 800 pound fish that goes for $25/pound even at the low end of the market... compare that to the typical farm catfish which might earn the farmer $10 gross.

Comment: @JohnO Just saying it as 489 pounds, so $12.5k rather than $1m. You're not wrong about tuna; just pick a canonical example ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Archer meant hunting for sport/pleasure had gone out-of-style, along with other "bad habits":
as mentioned by Commander Riker in First Contact: After first contact with the Vulcans, war, disease and pollution were quickly eradicated once humanity started pulling together.

Farming would still be necessary as not all food is replicated (any references comparing their food to the "real thing").

Comment: Also it is far from certain to say all people do not hunt, hundreds of year later Chakotay's father, who was a naturalist, would have almost certainly hunted his own food.

Comment: @Caimen - he would have eaten what he killed, not done it for pleasure. Even so, he as in a distinct minority, I'm using ALL in a general sense, there may have been 1 or 2 humans in the Federation (how many billion?) who did kill for pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Like many things in Star Trek this is one of those details about future human life that is thrown out because it is what the writers' consider chracteristic of an 'enlightened' society - not because it really makes any sense in the larger context of the fictional world that has been created. Unfortunately these little tidbits are more often reflective of the ideals held by typical left leaning urbanites that form a significant part of the hollywood machine. The quotes mentioned here are a case in point of the view that we 'enslave' animals and other such nonsense like the fact that there is no 'money' yet there is clearly commerce in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In TOS: 'All Our Yesterdays', Spock realizes something is wrong when he consumes meat. Quote: I’m behaving disgracefully. I’ve eaten animal flesh and I’ve enjoyed it. What’s wrong with me?

In a scene from Star Trek the Next Generation, 'Lonely Among Us':

> **Riker:** We no longer enslave animals for food purposes.
>   **Antican:** But we have seen humans eat meat.
>   **Riker:** You’ve seen something as fresh and tasty as meat, but inorganically materialized out of patterns used by our transporters.
>   **Antican:** Sickening!
>   (http://rodscuriosityshop.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/introducing-in-vitro-meat/)

So apparently they don't hunt or farm animals.

Comment: Okay but that is not Enterprise-era. In fact that is two distinct eras separated by like 100 years.

Comment: True enough. It was late when I posted and missed that distinction. I can see by the criticism that it's better to say nothing than be to incorrect or in error while in the company of such mighty men.

Comment: No need to get defensive. You made an error and I pointed it out. Move on!

Comment: Then I would say no need to be offensive. I only came to this site in hopes of getting an answer, which BBog was kind enough to provide. I decided to interact and made a technical error, and so get peppered with negatives and subjective edits for my effort? Is that how this site works? If this is the norm, you can keep it and I'll happily go back to my chess games and waste no more time here.

Comment: @Morgan: The negative votes are perfectly fine given that your answer has wrong information. Why would we make a positive/neutral vote? If we did that, we would be misleading visitors. Truly, don't take it personal - it isn't you, it is the answer itself.

Comment: @Morgan: Oh, and we also got Chess.SE :)

Comment: Omega, I'm new here and am still learning how things are done and what things mean. If no offence was intended and that's how it's done here then OK, I'm fine with that and apologise for my ignorance. I shall endeavour to do better. As for the chess, I play at a site with 30k active players with a million games in progress. Even so, I'll check the chess offering here at your recommendation. Thanks for your input and appologies to Lightness for my ignorance

Comment: @Morgan: No problem! Our chess site is great for strategy discussion and such. Not that I play chess anyway. Welcome to Stack Exchange though! These sites are definitely different from most forums and such, but they are very rewarding.

Comment: @Morgan: I don't believe that I have been offensive. You haven't been "peppered" with anything, and the edit was (a) unrelated, (b) _not_ subjective -- I formatted your post according to convention and the site guidelines. Thanks!

Comment: Vulcans are culturally a vegetarian group. They are not human, so spock is not a good answer to this. Additionally, Spock reaction is in context more about his **enjoying** the meat than simply the meat itself.